# MySQL and volumes in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I have an application that runs in a Docker environment.  I tried to configure docker  volume in a docker-compose file for persisting data written in MySqln  while executing `docker compose down -v`.

Here is my file :

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    container_name: db-server
    image: mysql:5.8
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p@$$w0rd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: apps
    volumes:
      - /home/john/myapp/volumes-sql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.14.2
  back-end-java:
    container_name: web-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-back
    restart: always
    image: web-server:$VERSION
    ports:
      - 8022:8443
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.14.3
networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 10.1.14.0/24
        gateway: 10.1.14.1
```

I recived this message after ran : `docker logs db-server` : `chown: cannot read directory '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted`

How can I resolve this problem ? and how can I use the volume when run `docker run` or `docker up -d`

Thank you

John.

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home/john/myapp/volumes-sql`?

Comment: I’ve tried with your compose file, no error occurred. Interesting. Please let us know if there is something new happened. But still, i would remind you that your error message occurred in the ENTRYPOINT of mysql:5.8, which is a shell script. There is a statement: chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql. You may put more attention in this.

Comment: Thank you , but i don't have ENTRYPOINT file in my application

Answer (score 0):

Any relation between the permissions on /home/john/myapp/volumes-sql and '/var/lib/mysql/' ??

0 drwxrwxr-x. 2 john john  6 Sep 24 08:10 volumes-sql

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: What are the permissions on /home/john/myapp/volumes-sql? 

it is : 0 drwxrwxr-x. 2 john john 6 Sep 24 08:10 volumes-sql

Comment: Yes , the permission is 0 drwxrwxr-x. 2 john john 6 Sep 24 08:10 volumes-sql